# Zoom in image while text is overlapping it (in the image)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Okay so I have this:

[image]

I want to add pictures in the Recommend 1, Recommend 2 ... I have achieved this using the `<img>` tag. But I have two problems:

1) It will not fit the square, it just sets the height and width of the image. (See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Opud.jpg )

2) I need the text to be on the bottom of the image / container (just like it is right now.) I tried fixing this with `position: absolute;`, but I got this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Buf.jpg . The image is top right for some reason.

I'm not using css **background image** because I need the zoom effect when the user hover over the picture.

Here is the HTML (for the 4 recommend elements):

```
<div class="col-xl-9 col-md-9 sec-three-right bg-primary">
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 text-center">
        <div class="col-xl-6 d-flex flex-column zoom">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/pickone.jpeg" alt="pickone" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="mt-auto right-pick">Recommend 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 bg-success d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="mt-auto right-pick"> Recommend 2 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 bg-danger d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="mt-auto right-pick"> Recommend 3 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 bg-info d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="mt-auto right-pick"> Recommend 4 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.sec-three-left {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.sec-three-right {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}    

.right-pick {
     margin-bottom: 25px;
     font-size: 25px;
     letter-spacing: 0.8px;
     color: white;
     text-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px black;
}

 .zoom {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
 }

 .zoom:hover img {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .zoom img {
       transition: all 0.4s;
       -moz-transform: all 0.4s;
       -webkit-transform: all 0.4s;
   }
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prozik/jvneLe9e/

I want it to look like this: 
[image]

I'm using Bootstrap v4.1.0 and jQuery 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem with `position: absolute;`:
Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="col-xl-9 col-md-9 sec-three-right">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 text-center">
            <div class="col-xl-6 d-flex flex-column zoom">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/pickone.jpeg" alt="pickone">
                <div class="mt-auto right-pick">Recommend 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-6 d-flex flex-column zoom">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/pickone.jpeg" alt="pickone">
                <div class="mt-auto right-pick"> Recommend 2 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-6 d-flex flex-column zoom">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/pickone.jpeg" alt="pickone">
                <div class="mt-auto right-pick"> Recommend 3 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-6 d-flex flex-column zoom">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/pickone.jpeg" alt="pickone">
                <div class="mt-auto right-pick"> Recommend 4 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.right-pick {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px black;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. You also have to remove default padding from the .col classes.

```
.right-pick {
    position:absolute;
    bottom :20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px black;
}
```

Fixed Code :-

https://jsfiddle.net/jvneLe9e/1/